# Using LoginView and LogoutView with custom templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the django.contrib.auth.LoginView and auth_views.LogoutView.as_view() with custom templates, without interfering with the admin site in any way, regardless the order at which the apps are loaded in the settings.py file. So far not succeeded.

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include 
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'}, name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'registration/logged_out.html'}, name = 'logout')
]
```

The login view loads my custom template, but the logout does not and uses the default one. Can't figure out why, no diagnostic appears in the terminal... Please help. Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572536/edit-django-admin-logout-template

Comment: Thanks but nope. This poster wants to change a template in the admin site, but I want to load mine instead outside of the admin site... ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With class-based views with `.as_view()` you are instantiating an instance of a view, so changed attributes need to be [passed into `.as_view()` method call itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf).

And if you want to render view template, not redirect to `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` - set [`next_page` to `None`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL).

```
path('logout/',
    auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/logged_out.html',
        next_page=None
    ),
    name = 'logout'
)
```

---

Yes, if your templates are loaded from inside each app's `templates` directory with 
[django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) (which is also the case if `settings.TEMPLATES[0]['APP_DIRS'] = True`) - Django will load /search for templates inside of each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, so in order to override `admin` templates you will need to use load them earlier in `INSTALLED_APPS` than `django.contrib.admin`.

However, this may not be always desired.

For more clarity you can use one global `templates` dir for your django project and apps in it and set its path in `settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']`.

Or, as far as you are already providing path to your custom template, use alternative name /path to avoid conflict with base templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Makes sense, did the changes. Logout still loads the djangoadmin logout template! ='(

Comment: Updated a bit answer. Also, is your template name actually correct (mb slight typo in name....) and present in specified templates path?

Comment: It only works if I load my app before the admin site in the settings.py. But then, the admin site views are overriden by the public ones and I don't want that either.

Comment: I think so. Everything works fine if I load my app in INSTALLED_APPS before the admin site. So the views are correct and in place. I am just not able to separate the two.

Comment: can you share your `settings.TEMPLATES` config?

Comment: Hi Oleg. Yes. Here it is.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I renamed the folder containing the templates to "my_registration" to avoid name collisions and now it works except the logout page, which still loads the django-admin one, and also loads sort like twice, embedded into itself twice. xD

Comment: This was solved assigning a next page to the logout url.
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="my_registration/logged_out.html", next_page = 'login'), name = 'logout')

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once, I changed the default template name from 'logged_out.html' to 'logout.html' and passed the new template name in the LogoutView as an argument.

```
path(
    "accounts/logout/",
    auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="registration/logout.html",),
    name="logout",
),
```

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Check the INSTALLED_APPS Setting of your project and make sure that

> django.contrib.admin

comes after your App(Account) application.

Both templates are located in the same relative path,

Django templates loader will use the first one it finds

Answer (score 0):

Thats because Logoutview is not rendering template it is redirecting to another url so you have to add this.

**views**

```
class LogOutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "registration/logged_out.html"
```

**url**

```
 path('logout-redirect/',LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout-redirect')
```

**and then in your settings.py**

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'logout-redirect/'
```

Comment: Many thanks. Won't the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL constant affect the admin site logout experience?

Comment: I believe not it is the only redirection

Comment: I tried many thanks, but still the django-admin logout template is rendered at http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/logout-redirect/.