# What does a class followed by method does in Python

Tags: python, django

In Django urls there is this code:

```
 path("login/", Login.as_view(), name="loggps")
```

`Login` is a class and `as_view()` is a method but is not in the `Login` class, probably is in a Parent class.

What does `Class.method` does in Python?

Comment: A method on a class is…well…a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) say as much on the first line.

Comment: FWIW, Django actually [defines](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9b0c9821ed4dd9920cc7c5e7b657720d91a89bdc/django/views/generic/base.py#L80) this a [`classonlymethod`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9b0c9821ed4dd9920cc7c5e7b657720d91a89bdc/django/utils/decorators.py#L6) but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as_view is a [classmethod](https://pythonbasics.org/classmethod/)

```py
class Login:
    @classmethod
    def as_view(self):
        print("hi")

Login.as_view()
```

Comment: But in Django source code the LoginView, which is the parent class, doesn't have the @classmethod decorator. BTW, I know the concept involved now, thanks!

Comment: Please read this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692899/using-loginview-and-logoutview-with-custom-templates and [class-based-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf)